# Ruby - Using syntactic sugar bracket method to return a value in 2-D array

Tags: ruby

A basic example of what is confusing me:

```
def [](row, col)
  self[row][col]
end

x = [[1,3], [4,5]]
x[0][0] #normal
x[0, 0] #syntactic sugar?
```

I have been told that these are equivalent statements, but when I run the sugar one, I get a different answer. How am I supposed to write it in syntactic sugar?

Comment: Forgot to add the method that was constructed to make this. Added it. Is the method invalid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your `def [](row, col)` method in a class that contains your data. So something like:

```
$ irb
2.3.0 :001 > class MyData
2.3.0 :002?>   attr_accessor :my_array
2.3.0 :003?>   def [](row, col)
2.3.0 :004?>     my_array[row][col]
2.3.0 :005?>     end
2.3.0 :006?>   end
 => :[]
2.3.0 :007 > x = MyData.new
 => #<MyData:0x007f96dc8024b8>
2.3.0 :008 > x.my_array = [[1, 3], [4, 5]]
 => [[1, 3], [4, 5]]
2.3.0 :009 > x[1,1]
 => 5
2.3.0 :010 >
```

Comment: Interesting... I didn't realize it had to be in a class to work

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with this:

1. You are adding your method to the `Object` class. But `Array` has its own `[]` which overrides the one in `Object`, so your method never gets called …
2. … which is a good thing, because it doesn't work anyway: all the method does is call itself, that *would* lead to a stackoverflow because of runaway recursion, but thankfully, the method calls itself with *one* argument, but is defined to take *two* parameters, and thus all you get is an `ArgumentError`.

Now, forgetting for a moment that monkey patching a core class is a **terrible** idea, you *could* to this:

```
module TwoDArrayExtension
  def [](x, y)
    super(x).method(__callee__).super_method.(y)
  end
end

class Array
  prepend TwoDArrayExtension
end

x = [[1, 3], [4, 5]]

x[0][0] #normal
# in `[]': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2) (ArgumentError)
# Hey, we just re-defined [] to take two arguments, so obviously this cannot work!

x[0, 0] #syntactic sugar?
#=> 1
```

This "works" in the sense that it gets your syntactic sugar example to pass. But your "normal" example now breaks: you have re-defined how arrays work, so you can no longer use it like an array. Tinkering with core classes like this has serious ramifications. For example:

- Irb is written in Ruby, and uses arrays internally, among other things. You cannot test your code in Irb, because it will just crash.
- The same applies to Pry.
- The same applies to any and all existing code that uses arrays … which is pretty much all Ruby code ever written. You cannot use any gems. You cannot use and standard libraries.
- In fact, in an implementation like Rubinius, where pretty much *everything*, including large parts of the core libraries themselves, and even the compiler are written in Ruby and thus use arrays internally, you probably won't even be able to get your code to run at all.

In short: yes, you can do this, but you really, *really*, **really**, **REALLY** don't want to.

Comment: Very well explained! Thank you